# Center scroll horizontally according to active link

Tags: jquery, css

How can I center the scroll horizontally according to active link using jQuery?

I am using `overflow-x: scroll;` in order to enable horizontal scroll but I wanted the scroll to be centred according to the active link.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/3859/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    });
}
```

Comment: Here's an idea... instead of moving the browser page, why not slide the nav bar over so that the link is centered? I think this would probably make for the best user experience. Use a combination of `position: relative;` and `position: absolute` with offsetting `left` or `right`

Comment: Hey thank you for your suggestion. I am currently trying to make the active link centred on the navbar. That would slide the navbar anyway. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I was just saying, since imo scrollbar manipulation is harder to deal with than element manipulation

Comment: I see, can you give an example?

Comment: Quick suggestion: You don't need the `$('a').each()` to remove a class from every `a` element, calling `$('a').removeClass('active')` is sufficient as it already iterates over all `a` internally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK you'll need to use JavaScript to scroll automatically when you land on the page. You can do something like...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var myScrollPos = $('a.active').offset().left + $('a.active').outerWidth(true)/2 + $('.menu').scrollLeft() - $('.menu').width()/2;
        $('.menu').scrollLeft(myScrollPos);
    });
});
```

You can adjust myScrollPos to get it to stop where you want it to, this should make it scroll to the left side of your active button. Breakdown below!

```
$('a.active').offset().left + $('a.active').outerWidth(true)/2
```

This gets us the button's distance from the visible edge of the element it's contained in, in this case the menu, then subtracts half the button's width to get the returned value to be the center of the button instead of the edge. It doesn't include any scrolling that's been done on the parent, so from here we add

```
+ $('.menu').scrollLeft()
```

Into the mix, that way we get the menu item's distance from the left, plus the current scroll position. The combination of the two gets us a consistent scroll coordinate between each button. Then, to wrap it up,

```
- $('.menu').width()/2
```

Offsets the scroll by negative 1/2 of your menu's width, effectively centering the button!

*Updated with the final solution!

Comment: With this code, the scroll is not triggered because `myScrollingElem` is not defined. It should be replaced with the selector of the element that is scrollable, in your case `.menu`. This makes it `$('.menu').scrollLeft(myScrollPos);`

Comment: Yup sorry, should have called that out!

Comment: Almost there =) https://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/3861/ Any idea on how to get the active item centred exactly in the middle?

Comment: Here you go! I set the max width of the nav to 300px for testing but it should be fine at whatever width you need. https://jsfiddle.net/will0220/efkpmfau/1/

Comment: yes! that was it! Mind explain the logic used there?

Comment: Sure thing! Adding it above so I can actually use formatting!

Comment: Great work @will, I've updated your fiddle and refactored the code a bit to make it more readable. I hope you don't mind. :) https://jsfiddle.net/efkpmfau/3/

Comment: Not at all! My original answer is updated with a breakdown of how I got the scroll coordinate, let me know if that makes sense!

Comment: One other note for you brunodd, you can apply similar logic using scrollTop instead of scrollLeft if you ever need to do anything related to scrolling down the Y-axis of a page

Comment: Great solution. But what about make spy scroll when you wheel your mouse?

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = document.querySelector(".menu a.active");
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth" ,inline: "center"});
});
```

might do the same.

Comment: This is great. Simple add the effect of being the "active" menu item in center, or atleast visible in active area.